# How to get the first visible columnindex in dataGridView1_Scroll event

Tags: datagridview, scroll

I wonder how to catch in the dataGridView1_Scroll event what column that is the first visible one. I try to do it in the code but are not sure I do it correct as e.NewValue seems to return a value of 575 in my case and I have only 31 columns?

Then in the button1_click event I want to programatically scroll to that column as the first visible one which is saved in: _globallastplanningscroll

What can I miss in the code?

```js
        int _globallastplanningscroll = -1;
        private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
            {
                _globallastplanningscroll = e.NewValue;
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = _globallastplanningscroll;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out the variable was a get; set; variable so the below does work:

```js
_globallastplanningscroll = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;
```